# Load files From SdCard to Webview nested urls

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, android-webview

I searched a bit about my issue over SO but couldn't be able to find out the solution so posting question over here.

Problem statement :

1. I am loading `index.html` from `sdcard/folder/index.html` to `Webview` 
   and this file includes several nested files meta info within folder like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"/>`
   so my base href is `<base href="file:///sdcard/folder/">` . Issue is that am getting **FILE NOT FOUND** or **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**.
2. Emulator deal with proxy for additional info . I use this `Webview` for loading index file where api's called inside in it . For example `api/v1` tag i am replacing with my domain or  ip url which i overrided methods are from webview client .
3. Url Manipulation not working on above methods , even though they are easily intercepted and tracked but on return url is not changed or manipulated .

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
   //I replace my url here 
   return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url)};
   ```

this replacing nested api calls doesn't change their super url .

These two issues are different than generally calling the first level of Webview calling by `loadUrl()` or `loadDataWithBaseURL()` so please read the statement properly and answer accordingly.

Comment: You dont have to supply a base href.

Comment: And where are the nested urls?

Comment: @greenapps that doesnt solve my problem and nested urls in dist folder in sdcard and index file loaded from it . Every ajax call is called from within dist or cdn.

Comment: What is a nested url? Where can i see one? What has this all to do with ajax calls?

Comment: @greenapps now consider it as a ip lookup or api call within a site ? may be cross origin